# What are the chances of drawing different mana producing sources in magic the gathering on your first turn. (assuming your the second player)

Tags: card-games, algorithmic-game-theory

There are a number of assumptions in the given scenario -

The first assumption is that the player is using a $60$ card deck.
The deck contains a ratio of $24:60$ lands so $24$ lands total.

They are the second player who draws a card on their first turn.

Of the given lands, there is $6$ mountains(which produce red mana),$10$ forests(which produce green mana) and $8$ sources that can generate both colors(both red and green mana).

Assuming the player has drawn a starting hand of $7$ cards. The hand contains $3$ lands $= 3$ cards that can produce mana. The hand contains one of each type of mana generator($1$ mountain, $1$ forest, $1$ that produces both).

What are the chances that this players next draw will be:

1). Any mana producing source?

2). A green mana producing source?  (including sources that can produce both)

3). A red mana Producing source?  (including sources that can produce both)

4). A source that generates both mana types?

Comment: Is 2/3 including just forest/mountain or is it including the dual land as well?

Answer (score 0):

After the hand has been drawn, there is a new ratio of $21:53$ lands to cards in the deck.

Of those $21$ lands, $16$ create green, $12$ create red(The red and green totals include the $7$ that create both), and $7$ create both.

Using this info the chances of the four questions are as follows -

1). $21/53 = 39.6226$ %

2). $16/53 = 30.1886$ %

3). $12/53 = 22.6415$ %

4). $ 7/53 = 13.2075$ %